# application.html.erb not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

well, the title by itself describes: the application.html.erb, even if I put this in the controller: layout "application"
well, here is the code of the application.html.erb, application_controller and public_controller:
https://gist.github.com/897408

Comment: What is loading then? Are u getting a error? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

All of your methods either use `render :text` or `render :partial`, neither of which make use of a layout. You need to create a view for each method. For instance, a view for `contact` in your `PublicController` would go in `views/public/contact.html.erb`. If you have a view at that location for `contact`, you don't need to put a `render` call at all.

Take a look at [this link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for some more basics on layouts and rendering.

Comment: that comment didn't come through -- what happens when you delete what?

Comment: ops, fail. when I delete this line: render :partial => "gallery_detail", now it shows this: Missing template public/gallery_detail with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rxml, :erb, :builder, :rjs, :rhtml], :formats=>[:html]} in view paths "/home/andrelima/workspace/cec/app/views", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-1.1.5/app/views" ...but there is a _gallery_detail.html.erb

Comment: you need to rename `_gallery_detail.html.erb` to just `gallery_detail.html.erb`, no underscore at the beginning. the underscore at the beginning is for partials only (and for a partial it would be named `_gallery_detail.erb`, without the `.html` part too)